# How to estimate tail distribution

Tags: statistics

I got asked this question during an interview with a bank for their market risk department:

You have a large set of historical data on stock price, however there are very limited data in the tail(say beyond the 95% percentile). Assuming you don't have the distribution for the data, how do you estimate/predict the tail/extreme events.

I was thinking about maximum likelihood estimation since I was given the data and I just need to calibrate the parameters so that $$L(\theta|x_1, X_2...X_n)$$ is at maximum.

But does it mean I need use non parametric methods?

I assume this is more of a open ended question, so any thoughts will be welcomed :)

Comment: @NormalHuman Here I think your bot is in error ("question" by itself adds no information, but "interview question" adds information about the open-endedness of the question).

Comment: What do you want to know/prove about the tail? If, say, you want to ensure that the distribution has finite mean, then there is actually nothing you can do without postulating a model for the tail. In other words, without postulating a model, basically all you can do is make statements whose truth is random, and assert that they are true with some large probability.

Comment: I guess, since it concerns a bank, that the theme would be risk.. How extreme are extreme events?

Comment: @fritzenbauer yes, its about risk!

Comment: @Ian Still incidental; compared to the important fact that distribution is unknown. I would rather have the latter in the title than the former.

Comment: @Ian I think they want me to predict the tail given historical data w/o distribution.

Comment: @NormalHuman Good point; perhaps a good title would be "how to estimate the tail of a distribution without direct measurement" or something similar.

Comment: @Dreamer In general you can't do it: with no assumptions, you can nonparametrically estimate the CDF of your random quantity, but not in such a way that you can truly *ensure* that the tail is "nice". On the other hand, you can postulate something about the tail, which might be *reasonable* given your data. Parametric estimation works this way.

Comment: @Dreamer Being explicit, supposing you have $N$ samples, your largest sample is $M$, and $x$ is some number greater than $M$. Then your $95\%$ confidence band for the probability of being greater than or equal to $x$ is approximately $[0,\frac{1.36}{\sqrt{N}}]$ (using the DKW inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality ) But this doesn't depend on $x$ at all, so the tail could potentially be very fat.

Comment: @Ian thanks for your input, do you mean that in order to model the behavior of a tail, you need to find a proper distribution, calibrate the model and then get estimation of the tail?

Comment: @Dreamer Again, it depends on what you want the tail to actually do. If you don't assume anything at all about the distribution, about the best you can do is make a confidence band for the CDF, to my knowledge. This might be good enough; it depends on the application. But if it isn't good enough, then you need additional assumptions to say much more.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, it makes sense!